# Datatables - Column Headers don't move when scrolling horizontally

Tags: datatables

I have a simple example of my problem.  I am using Datatables 1.9. The column headers don't move when scrolling horizontally when the datatable is inside another html table. It works fine when it is not in the html table. My example was actually taken from their example on horizontal scrolling but I added the outer table. Any help would be appreciated. I have looked everywhere for the answer. Here is the code. Thanks

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

</head>

<form>

<table>
<tr>
<td>

  <div id="demo">
  <table id="example">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Rendering engine</th>
  <th>Browser</th>
  <th>Platform(s)</th>
  <th>Engine version</th>
  <th>CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
  <th>Rendering engine</th>
  <th>Browser</th>
  <th>Platform(s)</th>
  <th>Engine version</th>
  <th>CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Trident</td>
    <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
    <td>Win 95+</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Other browsers</td>
    <td>All others</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>U</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</td>
</tr> 
</table>

</form>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').dataTable( {
  "sScrollX": "100%",
  "sScrollXInner": "110%"
  } );

} );

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/CHPqb/1/ Could you, please, explain more clear what exactly is the difference between your code and the example on datatables website?

Comment: Your fiddle shows the problem exactly.  Their example does not have the outer html table.  If you remove the <table>
<tr>
<td>
and the
</td>
</tr> 
</table>
above and below the div it will function properly.

Comment: Try to fix the outer table width http://jsfiddle.net/CHPqb/3/

Answer (score 11):

i had the same problem. I used this config

```
 "scrollY": "650px",
 "sScrollX": "100%",
 "scrollCollapse": true,
```

use **scrollCollapse** to make sure if you have less data, the bottom or footer does not stay at specified height.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks, I also made `scrollY = '100vh',` so it would expand to fit the length of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/CHPqb/23/

I added a css code and instead of sScrollXInner I change it to scrollX : true

```
th, td { 
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

$('#example').dataTable( {
   "sScrollX": "100%",
   "scrollX": true
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was

```
"sScrollX": "100%",
"sScrollXInner": "110%",
```

in the Jquery where I created the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead if using **"scrollX": true** move datatable inside a div:
`<div class='scroll'></div>`

And add CSS:
`div.scroll {
    overflow:auto;
}`

Comment: Why is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Move it into a div tag, and add `position:relative ;overflow:auto; height:500px;` to style.